# configurable value for header-portlet-javascript in liferay

Tags: header, liferay, portlet

Is it possible for header-portlet-javascript to pick up from system properties?

For example:

```
<header-portlet-javascript>${external.js.url}</header-portlet-javascript>
```

Comment: Hi, what is it that you'd like to achieve? Perhaps we can suggest an alternative to what you're attempting to accomplish since I don't quite understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

In general, this is not possible.

However, if it's ok that the Javascript you want to include occurs on every page of your portal, you could just add a reference to it inside your Liferay theme. Inside the theme, you can do dynamic stuff to retrieve the right JS url, e.g. using a portal property:

```html
#set($jsUrl = $propsUtil.get("external.js.url"))
<script type="text/javascript" src="$jsUrl"></script>
```

To have the same effect with System properties, things get a bit more complex. To my knowledge there is no way to get System properties from an injected Velocity variable. Therefore, we need to create a small event handler hook that will inject this property into the Velocity context.

### portal.properties

```
servlet.service.events.pre=my.custom.ServicePreAction
```

### ServicePreAction.java

```java
public class ServicePreAction extends Action {

    public void run(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Map<String,Object> veloVars = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        veloVars.put("externalJSurl", System.getProperty("external.js.url"));
        request.setAttribute(WebKeys.VM_VARIABLES, veloVars);
    }

}
```

### portal_normal.vm

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="$externalJSurl"></script>
```